# how to minify css in php style, script tag

Tags: javascript, php, minify

I wanted to minify a style tag or a script tag using PHP.
I have a style tag in my template and I needed to minify it so I can optimize my template.

Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
<style>
 My Style Goes Here
</style>

function minify_css(){
 This function should automatically minify the style above
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify

Comment: oh, thanks in advance for the link, but I think I didn't describe well my problem since I wanted to minify my tag using PHP. the PHP code it should be included in my files, not online.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You could use that PHP library to input your code and minify & print it out into the tag

Comment: ok, is there something like a plugin that I can add to my code.

Comment: Welcome to web programming and Stack Overflow. The website @Andrew Mast linked to is github, where developers share code. There is no simple PHP function to minify css and it is a quite heavy task so you need to integrate a library such as the one he linked into your project. But PHP is not the best language to handle that really